# I am getting an empty pie chart in my selenium (java) extent report. Its appearing all black

Tags: selenium, report, extentreports, extent

I am generating an extent report for my selenium test script.It is not a maven project. It's a simple java project. The version of extentReports jar used is 2.41.2. 
I am able to generate an html report but the problem is that the PASS/FAIL results are not reflecting in my extent report. I am getting an all black Pie chart in the report. Please refer the screen shot.
[Please refer the picture of my extent report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI1Wq.png)

---

Below is my code block :
GenerateExtentReports.java (This class contains the methods to generate the extent report) :

```
package SeleniumReports;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class GenerateExtentReports {
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest test;
ITestResult res;

@BeforeTest
public void reportSetup(){
    System.out.println("BeforTest_reportSetup");
    Calendar mycalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy_hhmmss");
    String timestamp=formatter.format(mycalendar.getTime());

    extent=new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/TestOutput/My First Report"+timestamp+".html",true);
    extent.addSystemInfo("Host Name", "Rashmi").addSystemInfo("Environment", "QA").addSystemInfo("User Name", "Rashmi Sharma");

    extent.addSystemInfo("Host Name", "Rashmi").addSystemInfo("Environment", "QA").addSystemInfo("User Name", "Rashmi Sharma");
    extent.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\extent-config.xml"));
    test=extent.startTest("loginUsingExcelData");
    System.out.println(extent.startTest("loginUsingExcelData").getRunStatus().toString());
}

@AfterMethod
public void getResults(ITestResult res) {
    System.out.println("AfterMethod_getResults");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(res.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS){
        //test.log(LogStatus.PASS, res.getThrowable());
}
    else if(res.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE){
        test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, res.getThrowable());
    }
    else if(res.getStatus()==ITestResult.SKIP){
        test.log(LogStatus.SKIP, res.getThrowable());
    }
    else if(res.getStatus()==ITestResult.STARTED){
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test started");
    }
    System.out.println("TestLogs conditions end here");
    extent.flush();
    extent.endTest(test);
    }}
```

---

loginUsingIterator.java (This class contains my test script) :

```
package SeleniumReports;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.File;

//import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

import java.io.FileInputStream;



import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

import SeleniumReports.MyMethods;

public class  loginUsingIterator extends GenerateExtentReports {
WebDriver dr;
FileInputStream fin;
XSSFWorkbook wb;
XSSFSheet sh;
XSSFCell cell;
XSSFRow row;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest test;

@BeforeClass
public void initialisation(){
    //extent.startTest("initialisation");
    System.out.println("BeforeClass_initialisation");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome selenium driver\\chromedriver.exe");   
    dr=new ChromeDriver();
    dr.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    dr.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
    //test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Navigating to URL");
    dr.manage().window().maximize();
    //dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='login']")).click();
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
@Test
public void loginUsingExcelData() throws Exception{


    //GenerateExtentReports extRep=new GenerateExtentReports();
    //extRep.reportSetup();

    fin=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\A638081\\SEL_Workspace\\ExtentReports\\TestData.xlsx");
    wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
    sh=wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator rows=sh.rowIterator();
    while(rows.hasNext()){
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='login']")).click();
    row=(XSSFRow) rows.next();
    if(row.getRowNum()==0){
        continue;
    }
    Iterator cells=row.cellIterator();
    while(cells.hasNext()){
    cell=(XSSFCell) cells.next();
    //cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).clear();
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    cell=(XSSFCell) cells.next();
    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='passwd']")).clear();
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='passwd']")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='SubmitLogin']")).click();

    MyMethods AddToCart=new MyMethods(dr);
    AddToCart.addingToCart();
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='logout']")).click();

    //test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Payment processed");
    //extent.endTest(test);
    System.out.println("first cycle completed");
    }
    }
    }
@AfterTest
public void quit() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Entered tear down loop");
    //System.out.println(test.getTest().getName().toString());
    //System.out.println(extent.get.getRunStatus().toString());
    fin.close();
    dr.close();
    dr.quit();
    }}
```

---

Can anyone help?
I am struggling since a week.

Comment: Looks like you're flushing the report *before* you end the test.  Flush should be the very last thing you do.  Could be you are aborting the entire report by flushing before ending.

Comment: @BillHileman Oh... I have tried that as well... But nothing is working... Is everything in my code okay??

Comment: A couple of things.  You are instantiating the report objects in the base class, but then you are defining them again in the extended class.  When you extend a class you don't declare the same class variables again.  Secondly, I don't see any test commands in the extended class that are not commented-out, so nothing is being done to an empty test object.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing ExtentHtmlReporter.
Change the below line in your code:

```
 extent=new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/TestOutput/My First Report"+timestamp+".html",true);
```

To

```
ExtentHtmlReporter extentHtmlReporter = ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/TestOutput/My First Report"+timestamp+".html"); 
Extent.attachReporter(extentHtmlReporter):
```